# Use multiple huge databases in one Entity Framework Core query with SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, orm, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.2

I want to query multiple tables from different databases in one single query with 1 or 2 `dbcontext`. I've been searching for some info, and it seems not easy to make it work perfectly.

I need to make several queries with 5 or 6 tables from 3 or 4 different databases at the same time.

- I've tried using the implementation of a `dbcontext` into the another but I'm having a problem with the primary keys which I don't have if I only use one database.
- I've tried 2 `dbcontext` separately, but I'm getting an error:

> Cannot use multiple DbContext instances within a single query execution message.

I've read that I can relate the 2 databases, the thing is I cannot do that because of the structure of my enterprise, and it doesn't allow me to.

This is in Entity Framework Core 2.2 or 3, I already tried both. I have already the databases created, so I scaffolded them.

I have a single example, with only 2 databases:

```
var data =
   from j in jsa.TbEmp
   join i in info.TbcEmpGral on j.fiEmp equals i.fiEmp
   where i.fiEmp == 361591
   select i.FcName.ToString() + " - " + i.fiDate.ToString();
```

Comment: Very bad, especially bad as you have "huge" databases. It will be exceptionally slow and resource intensive. I suggest you look into a way of copying all data into a single database and then querying that.

Comment: My team want to migrate to EFC for more code flexibility. We're trying to see which ORM is better and adaptive to our necessities, because we work with huge databases of budgeting and cost control. We are getting into EFC due to flexibility when mapping sql queries to objects and embedding SQL syntax when necessary. I'm not able to copy all data of one database to anothe because there are to many and the enterprise doesn't allow me to.

Comment: Are these databases on one server or multiple?

Comment: They are on one server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to query multiple tables from different databases [on one server] in one single query

The simplest way to do this is to create views or synonyms for all the tables in a single database.  EF won't be able to scaffold the model automatically, but if you create the model by-hand EF will simply send SQL to that single database *as if* it contained all the tables, and SQL Server will redirect the queries to the appropriate objects through the synonyms or views.

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking on creating a combination of Entity Framework and Views, because I see there's no an easy way to work this scenario using only EFC.

Comment: One reasonably-simple way to manage this kind of scenario is to create a dev database that has empty tables with all the correct primary and foreign keys and scaffold that.  Then at run-time point your DbContext to a database that has some combination of views, synonyms, and tables.

Comment: It makes sense, actually. Do you recommend using sp at some point? just for a few specific things or not at all?

Comment: Use stored procedures for batch processes, which EF can't support efficiently, and for complicated queries, and as an optimization for performance-critical queries where LINQ proves too slow.

Comment: Thank you for your advices!